# A protocol is telling me to encode the numeric value 150 to 0x01 0x50, and the value 35 to 0x00 0x35?

Tags: encoding, binary, hex, protocols

So I'm trying to implement the 'ECR' protocol that talks to a credit card terminal (Ingenico/Telium device in Costa Rica).

The documentation for the 'length' bytes states:

> Length of field DATA (it does not include ETX nor LRC)
>
> - Example: if length of field Message Data
>   is **150** bytes; then, `0x01 0x50` is sent.

I would think that the value '150' should be send as `0x00 0x96`.

I've verified that that is not a typo. In a working example message which has 35 bytes of data, they really do send `0x00 0x35`.

Am I missing something? Is this form of encoding the decimal representation of a value to its literal representation in hex a thing? Does it have a name? Why would anyone do this?

Comment: That sounds ***very*** weird. But banks are who I would expect to use / come up with such weird standards because they did not know any better and there was probably nobody with any IT knowledge around when the meeting took place that decided this :D

Comment: Maybe it's a  silly attempt at security by obscurity?

Comment: Could you maybe link to an actual doc that mentions this? Just for completion / clarity.

Comment: I think it's under an unneccesary NDA of sort, so sadly, no.
The doc is in a wild mixture of spanish and english, so I am guessing it came from the international manufacturer, and was hald translated and maybe modified by the local bank. They call it 'the ECR protocol'.

Comment: @luk2302: no, it is not weird. It is the usual "BCD": binary coded decimal. Intel CPU (before 64-bit) has instruction for that because banks: you force the CPU to work in decimal, so no divisions (and possible error) on displaying numbers or on having long numbers (for banks). Floating point units were not standard, and banks are still slow to upgrade systems and protocols.

Answer (score 3):

It has a name, and it was frequent in the past: it is **Binary coded Decimal** or in short BCD, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal.

In fact Intel CPU but the 64-bit versions had special instructions to deal with them.

How it works: every decimal digit is encoded in 4 bits (a nibble), so a byte can host two decimal digits. And you get string of them to describe integer numbers. Note: to convert to string (or back from strings): you divide the nibbles and then it is just an addition (`'0' + nibble`): the C language requires that character encoding of digits must be consecutive (and ordered).

If you works a lot with decimals, it is convenient and fast: no need to transform to binary (which requires shift and addition, or just multiplications) and back (again shift or divisions). So in past when most CPU didn't have floating point co-processors, this was very convenient (especially if you need just to add or subtract numbers). So no need to handle precision errors (which banks doesn't like; was the first movie of Super Man about the villain getting rich by inserting a round error on a bank system? This show the worries of the time).

It has also less problem on number of bits: banks needs accounts with potential billions with a precision of cents. A BCD makes easier to port program on different platforms, with different endianess and different number of bits. Again: it was for the past, where 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 36-bit, etc. were common, and no real standard architecture.

It is obsolete system: newer CPUs doesn't have problem converting decimal to binary and back, and we have enough bits to handle cents. Note: still in financial sector the floating point is avoided. Just integers with a fixed point (usually 2 digits). But protocols and some sectors tend not to change protocols very often (for interoperability).